# What does it mean when Stonehenge is "closed?"

Tags: uk, england, stonehenge, closures

I was in the UK near Christmas and was planning on going to Stonehenge, but it was apparently closed. I figured that Stonehenge was a natural destination and anyone could basically just drive up to it. So **what does it mean when it's "closed?"**

Comment: Worth noting that Stonehenge isn't exactly "natural" -  it was erected by civilized humans, and the current arrangement of the stones is a Victorian-era reconstruction.

Comment: @CMaster "Restoration" would probably be more accurate, there was some work done on straightening one of the stones to stop it from falling over during Victorian times, during which time it was moved by around half a metre.  The others were not moved.  Reconstruction implies the entire site was rebuilt, but that simply isn't the case.

Comment: @AdzzzUK it goes beyond straightening - numerous of the lintel pieces were lifted back in to place, and considerable amounts of concrete were poured. Reconstruction probably exaggerates things, but then "restoration" probably gives excessive credit to the archaeology used in the various moved stones. In fact, major changes contined through the 1950s also http://blog.english-heritage.org.uk/excavation-restoration-stonehenge-1950s-60s/

Comment: This is the footpath you can take any time https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-wiltshire-41567878 When I came by bike in 2016 it was not bad either, just a little bit farther.

Comment: Trifle not with the ways of druids, lest ye sprout holly from uncomfortable places! :-) The Google Maps views of it are pretty good - some from inside the ring, so you can get virtually "closer" than you could if you went there.

Comment: For those surprised by claims of it being a reconstruction, see https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/32583/was-stonehenge-built-in-the-1950s

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Stonehenge is situated on the edge of Salisbury Plain and as such is clearly visible from the A303 and a minor road that passes it. Yes, you can just 'drive up to it'. Viewing it from the road is somewhat hazardous, however, there being no pedestrian footpaths along those roads.

The actual site is managed by [English Heritage](https://www.english-heritage.org.uk/visit/places/stonehenge/) who control access, operate the visitor shop, cafe, museum and car park. If the Stonehenge is 'closed' it means that none of those facilities are available, and access to the space surrounding the stones won't be possible.

Note that the public are no longer allowed access to the stones themselves. The nearest one can get is about 10m away along a marked path. This is a sad reflection on the demands placed on such sites by visitors. (As a child in the Sixties I remember climbing on the stones!)

Comment: I believe its probably things like your experience from the sixties that has contributed to it being restricted to viewing from a small distance..

Comment: There are footpaths available very close to the monument. IMO the ticket is not worth its price.

Comment: Worth noting there have been plans in the pipeline for years to tunnel that section of the A303. It presents a huge bottleneck on a major road both due to it being around the point where the dual carriageway turns into single carriageway (which can't be dualled because of Stonehenge's proximity) AND being continually blighted with people rubbernecking Stonehenge. It might eventually happen at this point, which would make Stonehenge not visible from any roads.

Comment: @Muzer Worth noting though that those plans have been in the pipeline more or less ever since the stones were first erected

Comment: @Strawberry yeah, I should have emphasised that :D. Seems like we'll know whether or not it's cancelled again by this spring https://highwaysengland.co.uk/a303-stonehenge-home/ . Knowing Boris I wouldn't get your hopes up.

Comment: Incidentally, I think they fenced off the stones after some kid climbed on them in the sixties.

Comment: Whatever, this doesn't answer is it possible (and legal) to view the stones when it's closed? *"access to the space surrounding the stones won't be possible"* That's pretty vague. How close can you actually get when it's closed? Can you get to the path? neighbouring fence?

Comment: @smci Yes it's legal, yes it's possible. Just walk up to them when it's 'closed' it doesn't really matter. The over-priced café just won't be open. Oh well...

Comment: @Cloud: yes, that was my point to the respondent: to state that in black and white near the top of the answer.

Comment: @smci -- I think the answer is very thorough and answers my question well.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath That is not true, one may easily get the impression that one cannot get close enough to see the stones reasonable when it is closed. One can and there IS a footpath *very* close.

Comment: Rule #1 of public behavior control: if you are not OK with **everyone** doing X repeatedly and/or at the same time, X should be forbidden. Point-in-case, climbing Stonehenge. Heck, I'm pretty sure enough people touching the rocks can melt it.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath: it's unclear and contradicts itself as to how close you can/can't get when it's closed, which was the actual question: *"Yes, you can just 'drive up to it'... If it's closed, access to the space surrounding the stones won't be possible... The nearest [public access] can get is about 10m away along a marked path."* Well what's the answer? Does that mean you can or can't get 10m away when it's closed? 100m? view it from the roadside?

Comment: @smci -- I'll decide on my own whether this answers my question or not. (And it does.)

Comment: Fun fact: in the nineteenth century it was considered acceptable for visitors to chip off a little bit of the Stonehenge stones as a souvenir. They even rented you a chisel.

Comment: What do you mean that visitors demanded that the stones not be accessible?

Comment: @Gimmethe411 That's not what the sentence means. To "place demands on" something means to cause it cost/trouble/problems/effort - in this context it means that there were so many visitors, who wanted to do so many things (climbing, chiselling, touching) that the stones themselves were at risk of degradation. That constant tourist activity eventually had to be curtailed as a result.

Comment: @smci given that you can hardly avoid seeing them from nearby hilltops or when flying around the area in an aircraft, making it illegal to look at them would be problematic to say the least.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath: No. In order to make this a useful answer, the respondent needs to improve its clarity. Just because you are the OP, doesn't mean a conflicted and self-contradictory answer without any clear summary sentence, is ok. SE is for all of us, not just the OP.

Answer (score 28):

Stonehenge the tourist attraction is not just a natural destination. Like many sites that attract large numbers of visitors, there are timed tickets, admission fees, parking areas, a visitor center/exhibit, restroom, cafe, paved paths, shuttle buses, ropes to tell you where you can and can't stand, staff to oversee all this, etc... When the site is closed, that's all shut down. You can see this on [a map of the site](http://bodeswell.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Fullscreen-capture-582018-23502-PM.jpg), which shows the pathways and areas for ticket holders.

However, it is possible to [access the area without a ticket](https://www.packtolife.com/visit-stonehenge-free/), and you can still see the stones from outside the ticketed area on a nearby road (though as noted in that article, parking on the road is not permitted) or if you hike in. [This blog post](https://thirdeyetraveller.com/how-to-visit-stonehenge-for-free/) provides further details and illustrates the view from outside the fence and its proximity to the paid area (which is also some distance away from the stones, except for special tours and the solstices).

Comment: ... *They turned it to a stone museum, and now they charge you a sterling and a half just to see 'em*...

Comment: That last link is accurate. The others are out of date. in particular there is no public access to that dirt road. Additionally, while the paid area does not allow you to touch any stones, the path does cross the inner ditch and passes very close to the heel stone: [map](https://www.english-heritage.org.uk/siteassets/home/visit/places-to-visit/stonehenge/history/stonehenge-phased-plan-1.pdf)